# Why is Sequence an unsupported operand type for + in mypy?

Tags: python, typing, mypy

`mypy` is giving an error that `Sequence[str]` is not a supported operand type for the `+` operator:

```py
# test.py

from typing import Sequence


def test(x: Sequence[str], y: Sequence[str]) -> Sequence[str]:
    return x + y
```

```sh
$ mypy test.py
test.py:5: error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("Sequence[str]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

pytype gives a similar error:

```sh
$ pytype test.py 

[...]

  No attribute '__add__' on Sequence[str] or '__radd__' on Sequence[str]

[...]
```

Why is `Sequence[str]` an unsupported operand type for `+`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the doc, sequences do not necessarily implement `__add__`:

https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence

An example of a `Sequence` that doesn't support concatenation would be a `range`.

Comment: Thanks!  I had been looking at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations and I missed the "most" in "The operations in the following table are supported by most sequence types"...

Comment: So, what type hint should one use for a general sequence (accepting list, tuple, str) that does support concatenation by `+`? (Or should I ask this is a new question?)

Comment: Actually, it has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361188/python-typing-concatenate-sequences