# Python Typehints for Numeric Input

Tags: python, numpy, mypy, python-typing

I want to add typehints for mathematical functions in an existing codebase.
Most of the time the calculation itself is pretty easy and can be done both with pyhon numerics and numpy arrays.

However, I'm unsure how to typehinting the following function:

```py
def something(a, b):
    return a + b
```

This is what I tried already, I verify the typehints with mypy.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Union
from numbers import Number
import numpy.typing as npt
import numpy as np

def something1(a:npt.ArrayLike, b: npt.ArrayLike) -> npt.ArrayLike:
    return a + b #7
x1 = something1(3,4)

T2 = TypeVar('T2')
def something2(a: T2, b: T2) -> T2:
    return a + b #12
x2 = something2(3,4)

T3 = TypeVar('T3', bound=Union[Number, np.ndarray])
def something3(a: T3, b: T3) -> T3:
    return a + b #17
x3 = something3(3,4)

T4 = TypeVar('T4', bound=np.ndarray)
def something4(a: T4, b: T4) -> T4:
    return a + b # This works, but not with an python number
x4 = something4(3,4) #23

T5 = TypeVar('T5', bound=npt.ArrayLike)
def something5(a: T5, b: T5) -> T5:
    return a + b #27
x5 = something5(3,4)

T6 = TypeVar('T6', bound=Number)
def something6(a: T6, b: T6) -> T6:
    return a + b #32
x6 = something6(3,4) #33
```

mypy throws several errors for every function, so I'm unsure how to proceed.
This is the mypy output

```
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "str")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "bytes")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "generic")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "Sequence[Sequence[Any]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "_SupportsArray")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("float" and "str")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("float" and "bytes")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("float" and "generic")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("float" and "Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("float" and "Sequence[Sequence[Any]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("float" and "_SupportsArray")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("complex" and "str")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("complex" and "bytes")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("complex" and "generic")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("complex" and "Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("complex" and "Sequence[Sequence[Any]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("complex" and "_SupportsArray")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "float")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "complex")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "bytes")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "generic")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "Sequence[Sequence[Any]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "_SupportsArray")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("bytes" and "int")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("bytes" and "float")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("bytes" and "complex")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("bytes" and "str")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("bytes" and "generic")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("bytes" and "Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("bytes" and "Sequence[Sequence[Any]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("bytes" and "_SupportsArray")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("generic" and "int")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("generic" and "float")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("generic" and "complex")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("generic")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]]" and "int")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]]" and "float")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]]" and "complex")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("Sequence[Sequence[Any]]" and "int")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("Sequence[Sequence[Any]]" and "float")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("Sequence[Sequence[Any]]" and "complex")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("Sequence[Sequence[Any]]")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("_SupportsArray" and "int")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("_SupportsArray" and "float")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("_SupportsArray" and "complex")
runsomething.py:7: error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("_SupportsArray")
runsomething.py:7: note: Both left and right operands are unions
runsomething.py:12: error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("T2")
runsomething.py:17: error: Unsupported left operand type for + (some union)
runsomething.py:17: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("ndarray" and "T3")
runsomething.py:18: error: Value of type variable "T3" of "something3" cannot be "int"
runsomething.py:23: error: Value of type variable "T4" of "something4" cannot be "int"
runsomething.py:27: error: Unsupported left operand type for + (some union)
runsomething.py:27: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[complex, str, bytes, Any]", expected "T5")
runsomething.py:27: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "T5")
runsomething.py:27: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("float" and "T5")
runsomething.py:27: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("complex" and "T5")
runsomething.py:27: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "T5")
runsomething.py:27: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("bytes" and "T5")
runsomething.py:32: error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("T6")
runsomething.py:33: error: Value of type variable "T6" of "something6" cannot be "int"
Found 64 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Edit:
The errors are quite clear, so I'm aware it's not allowed to add `int` and `str` types. So I don't expect a clarification about all the erros, but a solution that will work for my usecase.
However, I find `something3` quite promising, but I have no clue what's the issue here.

Edit2: Added Comments for easier spotting the line numbers

Edit3: The question is **not about concatenation of sequences**, but about **adding two numbers, add numbers to arrays and add two arrays**. I just used '+' as the most simple mathematical operator.

Using Python 3.8.5, numpy 1.20.2 and mypy 0.812

Comment: This kind of thing is one of the reasons NumPy didn't bother with type hints for so long. I recommend continuing to not bother with type hints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python typing: Concatenate sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361188/python-typing-concatenate-sequences)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not about concatenation, I'm about adding two numbers, or in generall mathematical operations. I just used '+' as the simplest mathematical operator :)

Comment: I've tested the first variant from the possible dupe with integers and ``np.array``. It'll work for same-type arguments, but fail for mixed-type arguments (since inference degrades it to object).

Comment: @FranzForstmayr The other Q&A is basically about "how to apply <operation> to <complicated type group>". Concatenation is just their chosen use-case – just as addition is yours. (FWIW, I'm fine with this not being rated as a dupe.)

Comment: I edited the question, however another source of error, as `ArrayLike` allows `Sequences`, but the `+` operator is different on `Sequences` and `np.ndarray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work using [Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol)

```py
from typing import TypeVar, overload, Protocol

V = TypeVar("V", contravariant=True)
R = TypeVar("R", covariant=True)

A = TypeVar("A")
B = TypeVar("B")

class CanAdd(Protocol[V, R]):
    def __add__(self, other: V) -> R: ...

@overload
def add(a: CanAdd[A, B], b: A) -> B: ...
@overload
def add(a: A, b: CanAdd[A, B]) -> B: ...

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

add(1, 1)
add("abc", "123")
add(1, "abc") # error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "add"
```

Comment: This works, but seems quite verbose. Hopefully this will become easier in the future, maybe even a good solution from numpy itself.