# Solving "error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("Iterable[str]") [operator]"

Tags: python, token, mypy

I have code that accepts a list of strings, and turns them into a list of tokens (i.e. all strings are combined and flattened)

For example, `['a b', 'c', 'd e']` => `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

Like so:

```
l = ['a b', 'c', 'd e']
set(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b.split(), l, []))
```

Unfortunately, `mypy` is not happy, and it gives the message: `error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("Iterable[str]")  [operator]`.

As shown by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61861182/why-is-sequence-an-unsupported-operand-type-for-in-mypy) answer, it's because `sequences do not necessarily implement __add__`.

So, is there a way to use the code `set(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b.split(), l, []))` and have it be compatible with `mypy`?

Comment: not exactly an answer but what about using `set(chain.from_iterable(item.split() for item in the_list))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cast you can use lambda (else use a def function):

```
l = ['a b', 'c', 'd e']
reduce(lambda a, b: cast(list, a) + b.split(), l, [])
```